# Método espera un tipo de lista y al entregarsela, sale el error de convertir de double a decimal

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo, desarrollando uno de los métodos cuyo finalidad es tener el dato mas reciente del campo denominado IdLlanta, escribimos este código:

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/IdLlanta/Ultimo/Registro", Name = "GetLlantasIdLlantaUltimoRegistro")]
    public List<LlanHistoria> GetLlantasIdLlantaUltimoRegistro(string? IdLlanta)
    {
        try
        {
            var q1 = from a in context.LlanHistoria
                     where
                        a.id == IdLlanta
                     group a by a.id into GrupoA
                     select new TemStringDateTime
                     {
                         Texto = GrupoA.Key,
                         Fecha = GrupoA.Max(a => a.Fecha)
                     };
            var q2 = q1.FirstOrDefault();

            DateTime Fecha;
            if (q2 == null)
            {
                Fecha = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);
            }
            else
            {
                Fecha = q2.Fecha;
            }

            var q3 = from a in context.LlanHistoria
                    where
                        a.id == IdLlanta
                        &&
                        a.Fecha == Fecha
                    group a by a.id into GrupoA
                    select new CountCargo
                    {
                        Cargo = GrupoA.Key,
                        Count = GrupoA.Max(a => a.Registro)
                    };

            var UltimoRegistro = q4.FirstOrDefault();

            int RegistroEsperado = 0;
            if (UltimoRegistro != null)
            {
                RegistroEsperado = UltimoRegistro.Count;
            }

            var q5 = from a in context.LlanHistoria
                     where
                        a.Registro == RegistroEsperado
                     select new LlanHistoria()
                     {
                         Registro = a.Registro,
                         id = a.id,
                         Fecha = a.Fecha,
                         equipo = a.equipo,
                         Ubicacion = a.Ubicacion,
                         Horometro = a.Horometro,
                         Odometro = a.Odometro,
                         prof_1 = a.prof_1,
                         operacion = a.operacion,
                         estado = a.estado
                     };
            return q5.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return LlanHistoriaExcepcion;
        }
    }
```

Al ejecutar el código, pudimos notar que el método no estaba entrando al try sino a la parte del catch. Con el animo de identificar el punto preciso del error que obligaba a ejecutar la parte del catch, procedimos a realizar debug. Fuimos ejecutando uno a uno los pasos del método dentro del try. Al finalizar el try, sale el siguiente error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Decimal'.'
```

Los valores de los campos Horometro, odometro, prof_1 son del tipo decimal en la clase LlanHistoria, pero no entendemos de donde sale que estoy convirtiendo double a decimal. ya que el context.LlanHistorico también es del tipo LlanHistoria cuyo los datos en revisión también son decimal y de igual forma, el metodo esta esperando devolver una lista de tipo LlanHistoria.

Para dar mejor claridad, voy a mostrar la clase LlanHistoria.

```
public class LlanHistoria
{
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? equipo { get; set; }
    public int Ubicacion { get; set; }
    public decimal Horometro { get; set; }
    public decimal Odometro { get; set; }
    public string? operacion { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_1 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_2 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_3 { get; set; }
    public decimal presion { get; set; }
    public int salida { get; set; }
    public string? estado { get; set; }
    public string? situacion { get; set; }
    public string? observaciones { get; set; }
    public int bodega { get; set; }
    public string? usuario { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaIngreso { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
}
```

Agradecemos por favor su ayuda.

Comment: `context.LlanHistoria` también es de la clase que muestras o es otra?

Comment: Hola Mateo, es asi: public DbSet<LlanHistoria> LlanHistoria { get; set; }. Como puedes notar tambien es del tipo LlanHistoria.

Comment: Tienen el proyecto en github o algo que pueda descargar y depurarlo?

Comment: No Mateo, no lo tengo.

Comment: que linea da ese error?

Comment: si te fijas la linea, y los objetos que hay en esa linea, y depuras los objetos, te va a decir los tipos, y ahi vas a identificar cual es el double...

Comment: Hola gbianchi, el error lo tengo en esta linea: return q5.ToList(); Al revisar el objeto q5, y mirar tipos de elementos, encuentro estos errores: Method System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_CustomAttributes cannot be called in this context. Adicional a estos, aparecen mas errores con una particularidad, todos terminan asi: cannot be called in thid context.

Comment: Estimado German en otra de tus preguntas un usuario te comentó que tu estás complicando el código en exceso. La ingeniería de software es un proceso, no solo importa que el resultado sea el esperado, también importan el como se realizó: eficiencia, orden y limpieza son partes importantes de un código. Te señalo esto, porque no se entiende lo que hace tu código, por ejemplo tu primera consulta haces un `Where` a `a.id` y luego agrupas por la misma propiedad, esto no tiene sentido. Al ir agregando mal código corres el riesgo de obtener errores difíciles de detectar como en tu caso.

Comment: Para obtener un único registro con la fecha máxima simplemente debes hacer `var unicoRegisto = context.LlanHistoria.Where(a => a.id == IdLlanta).MaxBy(x => x.Fecha);`. Ahora si tu quieres una lista (porque pueden haber repetidos) : `var maxFecha = context.LlanHistoria.Where(a => a.id == IdLlanta).Max(a=>a.Fecha);
var lista=context.LlanHistoria.Where(a => a.id == IdLlanta && a.Fecha == maxFecha);`

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef por los comentarios. En medio de mi aprendizaje, cometo muchos errores, pero personas como ustedes, me ayudan a mejorar y profesionalizar mi labor. Continuare en la búsqueda de como identificar el error y su corrección con el animo de compartirla con otros usuarios. Nuevamente muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al consultar en el navegador Opera, específicamente utilizando la inteligencia artificial denominada Aria, encontramos esta información:

```
Al obtener una lista en C# con campos de tipo decimal, es importante recordar que al imprimir o visualizar los valores, estos pueden aparecer como si fueran de tipo double debido a la forma en que se manejan los tipos de datos en C#.
```

Debido a esto, cuando yo consulto la lista, ella tiene un conflicto porque los datos del tipo de lista que yo solicito son de tipo decimal (28 a 29 dígitos) y los que entrega son de tipo double (15 a 16 dígitos).

Una de las formas que encontramos para corregir el error, fue hacer una conversión explicita a los campos que deben devolverse como decimal así:

```
var q5 = from a in context.LlanHistoria
                     where
                        a.Registro == RegistroEsperado
                     select new LlanHistoria
                     {
                         Registro = a.Registro,
                         id = a.id,
                         Fecha = a.Fecha,
                         equipo = a.equipo,
                         Ubicacion = a.Ubicacion,
                         Horometro = Convert.ToDecimal(a.Horometro),
                         Odometro = Convert.ToDecimal(a.Odometro),
                         prof_1 = Convert.ToDecimal(a.prof_1),
                         operacion = a.operacion,
                         estado = a.estado
                     };
            return q5.ToList();
```

Importante tener presente esta novedad en c#, al momento de obtener las listas.